# How to migrate a TypeRegistryConfiguration class from Cucumber 4 to Cucumber 7?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I am migrating from `Cucumber 4` to `Cucumber 7` and I have the following class that defines Parameter types in my project (the class has hundreds of parameter types defined but for the sake of simplicity I only included one):

**TypeRegistryConfiguration.java**

```
public class TypeRegistryConfiguration implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Locale locale() {
        return ENGLISH;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
        typeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
                "list",
                "(\\S+)",
                List.class,
                (String s) -> Arrays.asList(s.split(","))
        ));
    }
}
```

I figured out how to adapt the `configureTypeRegistry` method to the new annotation method of defining parameter types by doing the following:

```
@ParameterType("(\\S+)")
public List<String> list(String s) {
    return Arrays.asList(s.split(","));
}
```

As for the `locale` method, I can't find how to set it now that the `TypeRegistryConfigurer` is not longer used for Cucumber behavioral configuration. I also need to know what it actually does, as far as I know it sets the language Cucumber uses to parse Gherkin keywords in feature files.